# Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/wabSpring]]

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8

I am trying to start spring boot app on tomcat.For that I deployed war file on tomcat, But I am getting `Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/wabSpring]]`. I search for this on google but no solution worked for me. Please tell me why I am getting this error.

I am using tomcat 8.5 and spring version 2.0.6

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException 
{
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new 
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class);
        context.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = 
container.addServlet("dispatcher", new 
     DispatcherServlet(context));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.springboot.wabit.*" })

public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
private WebFlowConfig webFlowConfig;

public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new 
  InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new 
 CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(2000000);  
    return multipartResolver;
}


@Bean
public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
    FlowHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
    handlerAdapter.setFlowExecutor(this.webFlowConfig.flowExecutor());
    handlerAdapter.setSaveOutputToFlashScopeOnRedirect(true);
    return handlerAdapter;
}

@Bean
public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
    FlowHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
    handlerMapping.setFlowRegistry(this.webFlowConfig.flowRegistry());
    return handlerMapping;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer 
configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}


@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
    .allowedOrigins("*")
    .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
    
}

}
```

**WebFlowConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.springboot.wabit.*" })
public class WebFlowConfig extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {

@Autowired
private AppConfig AppConfig;

@Bean
public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
    return 
getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry()).addFlowExecutionListener(new 
   SecurityFlowExecutionListener(), "*")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
    return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder().setBasePath("/WEB- 
INF/views/flows")
            .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml").build();
}

@Bean
public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
    return   
   
getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder().
setViewFactoryCreator(mvcViewFactoryCreator())
 .setValidator(validator()).setDevelopmentMode(true).build();
}

@Bean
public MvcViewFactoryCreator mvcViewFactoryCreator() {
    MvcViewFactoryCreator factoryCreator = new MvcViewFactoryCreator();
    factoryCreator.setViewResolvers(Collections.singletonList
    (this.AppConfig.viewResolver()));
    factoryCreator.setUseSpringBeanBinding(true);
    return factoryCreator;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}

  }
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet- 
    class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>2097152</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>4194304</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter- 
class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:wf="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow- 
config.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.springboot.wabit" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
     
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.
support.StandardServletMultipartResolver" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/assets/"
    mapping="/resources/**" />

<wf:flow-executor id="flowExecutor"
    flow-registry="flowRegistry" />

<wf:flow-registry id="flowRegistry"
    base-path="/WEB-INF/views/flows"
    flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
    <wf:flow-location-pattern
        value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
</wf:flow-registry>

<wf:flow-builder-services
    id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator"
    validator="validator" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    <property name="order" value="-1" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewFactoryCreator"
    class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
    <property name="viewResolvers" ref="viewResolver" />
</bean>

    <bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.
   beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
   </beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  
   <modelVersion> 4.0.0 </modelVersion>
   <groupId> com.springboot </groupId>
   <artifactId> wabit </artifactId>
   <version> 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT </version>
   <packaging> war </packaging>

<name>wabit</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF- 
8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- database connection pooling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>wabSpring</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

   </project>
```

**Log**

```
 *Oct-2020 11:26:03.558 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-52] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/wabSpring]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1634)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:286)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1565)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:207)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1626)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.springboot.wabit.config.WebAppInitializer.onStartup(WebAppInitializer.java:26)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5144)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 48 more*
```

Is there anything I need to change in WebAppInitializer file? My apllication start on tomcat if I do not include dispatcher-servlet.xml file, but I dont think thats good way to start the app.

Comment: Which is line **26** in `WebAppInitializer.java`? --- How is `WebAppInitializer` registered? There are no annotations on the class.

Comment: This is Spring Boot according to your question and tags, however, why do you disable all the Spring Boot things? You are manually setting up everything. [The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) explains what you need to do to get your Spring Boot application deployable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete your `web.xml`
2. Delete your `WebAppInitializer`
3. Delete your `dispatcher.xml`
4. Remove `@CompoentScan` from your `WebFlowConfig`
5. Cleanup your `AppConfig` (only leave the WebFlow configuration stuff)
6. Put properties in your `application.properties`
7. Let your `@SpringBootApplication` extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`
8. Build and deploy.

Your `AppConfig` does too much and disables Spring Boot auto-config only leave the WebFlow configuration.

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final WebFlowConfig webFlowConfig;

    public AppConfig(WebFlowConfig webFlowConfig) {
      this.webFlowConfig=webFlowConfig;
    }

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
        FlowHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
        handlerAdapter.setFlowExecutor(this.webFlowConfig.flowExecutor());
        handlerAdapter.setSaveOutputToFlashScopeOnRedirect(true);
        return handlerAdapter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
        FlowHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
        handlerMapping.setFlowRegistry(this.webFlowConfig.flowRegistry());
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```

Your `

```java
@Configuration
public class WebFlowConfig extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
        return 
    getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry()).addFlowExecutionListener(new 
       SecurityFlowExecutionListener(), "*")
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
        return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder().setBasePath("/WEB- 
    INF/views/flows")
                .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml").build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices(MvcViewFactoryCreator viewFactoryCreator, Validator validator) {
        return   
       
    getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder().
    setViewFactoryCreator(viewFactoryCreator)
     .setValidator(validator).setDevelopmentMode(true).build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MvcViewFactoryCreator mvcViewFactoryCreator(List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers) {
        MvcViewFactoryCreator factoryCreator = new MvcViewFactoryCreator();
        factoryCreator.setViewResolvers(viewResolvers);
        factoryCreator.setUseSpringBeanBinding(true);
        return factoryCreator;
    }

  }
```

You already should have an `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, if you don't create it and place it in `com.springboot.wabit` (as I assume that is your top-level package) and have it extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`. As explained as well in [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(YourApplication.class);
  }
}
```

Now as you removed some beans from the `AppConfig` class you will need to add some properties to the `application.properties` to achieve the same.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsps

spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize=2MB
```

Finally your dependencies are a bit of a mess you don't need the `servlet-api`, `javaassist` and `maven-shade` dependencies. Either you don't need them or they are already included in the `spring-boot-starter-*` projects you import.

Comment: As per your answer im getting this message on console . 
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  appConfig defined in file [E:\wabit\target\classes\com\springboot\wabit\config\AppConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  webFlowConfig (field private com.springboot.wabit.config.AppConfig com.springboot.wabit.config.WebFlowConfig.AppConfig)

Comment: my appication started successfully I removed web.xml, dispatcher-servlet, WebAppInitializer.java form project.

Comment: Didn't see the reference in the config, added an updated WebFlowConfig to the answer as well (that is also doing too much configuration). The problem with your configuration is that it works around Spring Boot instead of leveraging it. The adapted config uses Spring Boot to its advantage. Instead of 2 config classes you could also merge them into one or at least move all the Web Flow configuration into a single one (so move the `FlowHandlerAdapter` etc. ).